# strategically placing array elements in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with a list of objects. What i'm trying to achieve is I want to read every object in the array and append the value to a div by following certain rules. The rules are: First, read the key of the object, for example, 1st object is `{1: 'test_12'}` you have to read the key which is 1. Second, get the value of that key. Third, append it to div `top` or div `bottom`. Now here is where it gets a little complicated. When you append it to the divs its placement should be strategic I want to have 5 of the object values on div `top` and the other 5 on div `bottom`. Now the objects with keys 1 and 2 are not equal. When you append their values, they should be placed without having two values with the same keys next to each other. Now as I mentioned the objects with keys 1 and 2 are not equal so there are going to be some values appended to the divs that are going to end up next to each other but the goal is to reduce that to the maximum possible. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

**NOTE1:** Please run the code first and take a look at how the 2 divs (`top` & `bottom`) elements are placed. They are placed strategically so that it will show you what I want the final product to look like.

**NOTE2:** I have added a rough js sketch with comments to show what I'm trying to achieve.

**NOTE3:** I want the solution to work with any array length and should not only be limited to this question's array length!

```js
const myArray = 
  [ { 1: 'test_12' } 
  , { 2: 'test_13' } 
  , { 2: 'test_14' } 
  , { 1: 'test_15' } 
  , { 2: 'test_16' } 
  , { 2: 'test_17' } 
  , { 2: 'test_18' } 
  , { 1: 'test_19' } 
  , { 1: 'test_20' } 
  , { 2: 'test_21' } 
  ] 

let newArray = []

//something like this (this is just a very rough sketch!!)
myArray.forEach((obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    //if the newArray is empty push a random array to it
    if (newArray.length == 0) {
      newArray.push(myArray[(Math.random() * myArray.length) | 0])
    }
    //get the last element in the newArray and check if its key is 1 or 2
    else if (Object.keys(newArray.at(-1))[0] == 1) {
      //get a random object from myArray with key 2 and push it to newArray
      //if none are found push what ever object you find
    } else if (Object.keys(newArray.at(-1))[0] == 2) {
      //get a random object from myArray with key 1 and push it to newArray
      //if none are found push what ever object you find
    }

    //once looped through every myArray objects and newArray is fully constructed get every element from newArray and append the first 5 objects value to div top and the last 5 objects value  to div bottom
    newArray.slice(0, 5).forEach((obj) => {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        $('.top').html(`<p>${obj[key]}</p>`)
      });
    });
    //for the last 5 newArray elements
    newArray.reverse().slice(0, 5).reverse().forEach((obj) => {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        $('.bottom').html(`<p>${obj[key]}</p>`)
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: pink;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--I want the final product to be something like this-->
<div class="top">
  <p>test_12</p>
  <p>test_13</p>
  <p>test_21</p>
  <p>test_19</p>
  <p>test_16</p>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <p>test_18</p>
  <p>test_15</p>
  <p>test_14</p>
  <p>test_17</p>
  <p>test_20</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the following a correct summary? For each object, if its key is 1 then its value will go in "top" and if its key is 2 then its value will go in "bottom". Within each of those two divs, you want the values distributed so that no two adjacent values are consecutive (i.e. `test_14` should not be adjacent to `test_15`).

Comment: @kmoser yes test_14 and test_15 should not be consecutive

Comment: If the original array contains more than 10 elements, do you still want to limit "top" and "bottom" to 5 elements each?

Comment: @MORÈ its because if test_15 is above, the bottom div will have many consecutive object key 2’s

Comment: @kmoser no you can add more to each div once the first div is full move to the next div

Comment: What do you mean by "full?"

Comment: @kmoser i mean say the newArray has length of 23 place 12 on top and 11 on bottom

Comment: I did not get what you want. But if this helps Create 2 arrays "topArray" and "bottomArray" and check if the value exists then do not included it. finally loop through each 2 arrays and append to DIV. remember to use Math.floor in your random element selection.

Answer (score 0):

In bellow code the input array is sored as match as possible and return two arrays. One with sorted element with different keys, Other with all remained unique keys.
I merged the arrays to slice them with 5 items for topArray and bottomArray. you can modify it based on your need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .top {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      width: 100%;
      height: 3em;
      background-color: pink;
    }

    .bottom {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      width: 100%;
      height: 3em;
      background-color: gold;
    }
  </style>

  <!--I want the final product to be something like this-->
  <div class="top">
    <p>test_12</p>
    <p>test_13</p>
    <p>test_21</p>
    <p>test_19</p>
    <p>test_16</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>test_18</p>
    <p>test_15</p>
    <p>test_14</p>
    <p>test_17</p>
    <p>test_20</p>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    const myArray = [{
        1: 'TEST_12'
      },
      {
        2: 'TEST_13'
      },
      {
        2: 'TEST_14'
      },
      {
        1: 'TEST_15'
      },
      {
        2: 'TEST_16'
      },
      {
        2: 'TEST_17'
      },
      {
        2: 'TEST_18'
      },
      {
        1: 'TEST_19'
      },
      {
        1: 'TEST_20'
      },
      {
        2: 'TEST_21'
      }
    ];

    function sortByKey(Arr, srt = []) {
      let newArr = []
      for (let i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
        if (srt.length == 0) {
          srt.push(Arr[i])
        } else if (Object.keys(srt.at(-1))[0] !== Object.keys(Arr[i])[0]) {
          srt.push(Arr[i])
        } else {
          newArr.push(Arr[i])
        }
      }

      if (newArr.some(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(srt.at(-2))[0]))) {
        return (sortByKey(newArr, srt));
      }
      return [srt, newArr];
    }

    let [sorted, singleKey] = sortByKey(myArray);
    
    let topArray = bottomArray = [...sorted,...singleKey]

    $('.top').html(``)
    topArray.slice(0, 5).forEach((obj) => {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        $('.top').append(`<p>${obj[key]}</p>`)
      });
    });
    //for the last 5 newArray elements
    $('.bottom').html(``)
    bottomArray.reverse().slice(0, 5).reverse().forEach((obj) => {
      Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
        $('.bottom').append(`<p>${obj[key]}</p>`)
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Here is where you misunderstood my question. You said "they should be placed without having two values with the same keys next to each other in the TOP DIV." What I want is to place the values without having two values with the same keys next to each other in both the TOP DIV and bottom DIV.

Comment: This sort all the objects with different keys and puts all the remained unique keys in the other array.